# Can an unlocked Nexus One without a carrier be used as a standalone device?

Tags: nexus-one, sim-unlocking

I'm interested in playing around with the new open android open accessory development kits but don't want to pay a monthly fee for having a cell-phone. If I buy the Nexus One/S unlocked and forgo getting a wireless carrier, would I still have access to the full set of phone features minus 4G/Calls/Texting? In the past, cellphones minus the carriers were crippled from doing anything useful. I'm wondering if this is still the case with the newer smart phones. Essentially it'd be an android-powered iPod Touch.

Comment: Google Voice gives you free SMS, so without the data/cell plan you can still text to your heart's content over WiFi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it works fine for me without SIM-card. I can still use WiFi for accessing Internet.

Comment: Do you get a constant message telling you to insert a SIM card or does it look the same?

Comment: @awithrow: No, I don't. It works just as a laptop connected to the WiFi.